How to display local HTML files in Flet's WebView in Android device?
I have problems with the WebView element in Android.
I would like to display local HTML files with JavaScript and CSS.
My first attempt was to use directly local files:
When I use file:// scheme, it seems not to work.
So I've created a local server with http.server and I call http://localhost:8000/file.html.
import flet as ft
import http.server
import socketserver
import threading
import sys
import ssl

SERVER = "localhost"
PORT = 8000
HTML_DIRECTORY = "assets/html"


class HookHandler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, directory=HTML_DIRECTORY, **kwargs)

class ThreadedTCPServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, socketserver.TCPServer):
    pass

def start_server():
    with ThreadedTCPServer((SERVER, PORT), HookHandler) as httpd:
        httpd.serve_forever()


def main(page: ft.Page):
    wv = ft.WebView(
        f"http://{SERVER}:{PORT}/file.html",
        expand=True
    )
    page.add(wv)

server_thread = threading.Thread(target=start_server)
server_thread.daemon = True
server_thread.start()
app = ft.app(main)

But when I access the files, there is a security error ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED. I find no way to disable this security in the WebView component.
So I've added SSL to my server, with self signed certificate for localhost and I call http://localhost:8000/file.html.
import flet as ft
import http.server
import socketserver
import threading
import sys
import ssl

SERVER = "localhost"
PORT = 8000
HTML_DIRECTORY = "assets/html"


class HookHandler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, directory=HTML_DIRECTORY, **kwargs)

class ThreadedTCPServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, socketserver.TCPServer):
    pass

def get_ssl_context(certfile, keyfile):
    context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER)
    context.load_cert_chain(certfile, keyfile)
    return context

def start_server():
    with ThreadedTCPServer((SERVER, PORT), HookHandler) as httpd:
        context = get_ssl_context("cert.pem", "key.pem")
        httpd.socket = context.wrap_socket(httpd.socket, server_side=True)
        print("Serving at port", PORT)
        httpd.serve_forever()


def main(page: ft.Page):
    wv = ft.WebView(
        f"https://{SERVER}:{PORT}/file.html",
        expand=True,
    )
    page.add(url_input, submit_btn, wv)


server_thread = threading.Thread(target=start_server)
server_thread.daemon = True
server_thread.start()
app = ft.app(main)


When I open my application, it's blank.
If I open the same URL in my Android's Firefox browser, I see a security alert (because the certificate is self signed), but I can check "I'm OK, continue" and the HTML file is well rendered.
My question : How can I display local files with Flet's WebView?
After a lot of searching, I've found a workaround that does't satisfy me: modify the Androidmanifest.xml to add a android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" property.
But this implies to decompile APK, modify the file by hand, compile a new APK, sign this APK.
Is there a way to add custom elements / properties in this file automatically in the flet build apkcommand?

To modify the AndroidManifest.xml:

Clone a template repository (https://github.com/flet-dev/flet-build-template).
Modify the AndroidManifest.xml file located in flet-build-template\{{cookiecutter.out_dir}}\android\app\src\main.
When building, use --template-dir option.

Example:
flet build apk --include-packages flet_webview --template-dir C:\Users\PhunkyBob\flet-build-template
APK file will use this modified manifest and will be correctly signed.
